# how to get variability of random numbers

Tags: random

I want to get random numbers that are not always the same, in my code now I'll either get all `-0.5` or all `0.5` which is exactly what I don't want. What I want is some real variability, such as maybe a `-0.1`, and a `0.33`, and possibly a `-0.0666` --> you get the picture- **actual randomness**!

I've been searching high and low for this- how could this information not be easily found on stackoverflow- I hope this question will remedy that.

If someone could point me the way- and if they could point the way toward a Gaussian distrobution of randomness- that would be delicious.

My code is looking like this:

```
    //MAKE SURE YOU HAVE ONE FOR BIAS
    for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
    {
        weights_one[j] = randoDub(0.5, 0.5);
    }


    for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
    {
        System.out.println("weights_one[" + j + "]: " + weights_one[j]);
    }





    //now that we have inputs --> we must initialize the weight vectors

    //then we do our calculation // our rule --> and then we are finished. 


}



public static double randoDub(double min, double max) throws InterruptedException 
{

    Random rand = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

    double randomValue = min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble();

    //DELAY FOR SEED CHANGE
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    return randomValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `randoDub` with the same arguments for `min` and `max`. You probably want `randoDub(-0.5, 0.5)` instead of `randoDub(0.5, 0.5)`.

As a word of advice, to avoid sleeping inside the function, instead create a `Random` object outside of `randoDub` and pass it in.